# Fullcalendar - External links

Tags: fullcalendar

Is it possible to go to the start of an event based on an external link.

Example...

```
<li><a href="javascript:">Tuesday 10/8/13 10:00 am</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:">Tuesday 10/8/13 1:00 pm</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:">Tuesday 10/8/13 2:00 pm</a></li>
```

Upon clicking one of these links, i'd like to have my FullCalendar implementation scroll to that date/time.

Similar to the way this works, only going to the day/time of an event

```
$('#button').click(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('today');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use FullCalendar's [gotoDate](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/current_date/gotoDate/) method. You'd just need to pass in the date parameters in the correct format.

```
.fullCalendar( 'gotoDate', year [, month, [ date ]] )
```

Comment: I tried 'gotoDate' a while back, but it only allows me to target a date, not the date and time as i'm needing.

Comment: @kojay, There is no built in way to jump to a time after the calendars initialization that I'm aware of. There is an open feedback ticket for this request that has a user submitted workaround: http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=196